# cd to a path containing spaces using a path variable

Tags: quoting, variable, cd-command

I have a file containing a list of commands which I run from my `.bash_profile` as

```
source my_cmds
```

For eg:

```
$cat my_cmds 
scripts=~/scripts
```

assuming my `$HOME` is `/Users/knayak`, when I run
`cd $scripts` in the prompt, it takes me to `/Users/knayak/scripts`

Now, I have a path in this form(which cannot be renamed for some reasons), for which I don't know how to set a command variable so that I can `cd $path` using that variable.

```
/Users/knayak/Somedir - some name Inc/Tasks
```

I tried adding all these in my `my_cmds` file to set an environment variable `tasks`,

```
$cat my_cmds 
tasks=~/Somedir - some name Inc/Tasks
tasks="~/Somedir - some name Inc/Tasks"
tasks=~/"Somedir - some name Inc/Tasks"
...
```

and many more, including single quotes in some, but none of them seem to work when I do `cd $tasks`. Most of them fail with the error.

> cd: "/Users/knayak/Somedir: No such file or directory

I need to set the proper value in the form `tasks=~/<whatever>` 
for `cd $tasks` to work with this path?

Comment: `cd "$tasks"` .

Comment: `tasks=~/"Somedir - some name Inc/Tasks"` and `cd "$tasks"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, Quote your variable expansions.

If the file `my_cmds` is:

```
$ cat my_cmds 
tasks=~/"Somedir - some name Inc/Tasks"
```

And the file `./bash_profile` contains (among other lines):

```
$ cat ~/.bash_profile
[ -f ~/my_cmds ] && . ~/my_cmds
cd "$tasks" && pwd
```

Executing ~/.bash_profile will show:

```
$ sh ~/.bash_profile
/Users/knayak/Somedir - some name Inc/Tasks
```

Comment: Great! Thanks...and sorry for a dumb question!